# Php Phalcon with Smarty template

Tags: php, smarty, phalcon, volt

I am trying to do sample application [a link]http://invo.phalconphp.com/ with Smarty template. Can anyone suggest me what is the equalent content() inside volt template to smarty template.

Any example Please let me know.

Thanks,
Raja K

Comment: Perhaps you could give some more information? A snippet from your Smarty template? I'm thinking this question is mostly about how Smarty works, since you're looking for Volt's content() equivalent in the Smarty-engine?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for that. Php Phalcon Incubator suggest to use Smarty engine and doesn't provide any example how to proceed it

Comment: So I'm searching a bit for what your problem actually is. If you are not familiar with Smarty, and therefor don't know the equivalent content() function, why do you want to use Smarty instead of Volt? Disclaimer: I have not used Smarty in a few years, I have a reasonable amount of experience with Phalcon and Volt.

Comment: We are trying with Smarty. I have updated the view with Smarty component, But my content still showing { $title } seems like it's not interpreting . Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Could you update your question with the configuration of your DI? Should be in services.php if you followed invo example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two issues here. Your problem with not finding the equivalent to content() stems from the fact that Smarty handles inheritance of templates differently. The `{ $title }` not working as expected comes from the whitespace after and before the accolades. Change it to `{$title}`.

Comment: Hi, I getting the content in text format while using {content}. Am i missing anything ?

Comment: $this->_view->setContent($this->smarty->fetch($path)); Is anything wrong with this line in Smarty.php in Phalcon Lib ?

Comment: As far as I have read and tested in a few minutes {content} is not valid Smarty syntax. If you put a variable content on your view in your controller, you would use it in Smarty as: {$content}  <-- note the dollar sign... And I am really curious still why you want to use Smarty? It seems you are not really familiar with Smarty either, so why not just learn first about Phalcon + Volt before trying to switch to Smarty? What are your motivations for using Smarty?

Comment: Yes, It seems like smarty is very well in the market and Instead of trying volt, we would like to try with volt.